# No warning message generated by g++ when using [[nodiscard]] and compile with lower stl option

Tags: c++, stl

is there nodiscard attribute available in c++11? If not, why no warning message output by g++

code belows.

```
//test.cpp
#include<iostream>

[[nodiscard]] int foo() {
  return 1;
}

int main() {
  std::cout<<foo()<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

At the beginning, i complie the program by "g++ -std=c++20 test.cpp -o test.o" and everythings is fine.

But then i want to see what the exact version that g++ can not support the attribute [[nodiscard]]. So i change the complier option to "g++ -std=c++11 -Wall test.cpp -o test2.o" and no error message output by g++ and test2.o works well.

According to chatgpt, warning message will shown at 8.1 gcc version and my gcc version is 11.3.0.

I wonder if it is because of the Updated version gcc have made some update which allows lower version of c++ stl support it? Or for other reasons?

Comment: But the result of `foo()` is used and is not discarded.  So the attribute is being honoured. Code that does show the effect of the attribute - live - https://godbolt.org/z/1cGdKnT5c

Comment: Unknown attributes can be ignored by the compiler. That allows one compiler to skip custom attributes defined by another compiler. And in C++11 nodiscard is not "known".

Comment: You print out the result, so you haven't discarded it.  To discard means to never even use, not just store in a variable.

Comment: chatgpt does not understand c++. It can produce nice looking prose, but when it comes to facts, you can as well roll dices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[dcl.attr.grammar]/6` states that

> For an attribute-token (including an attribute-scoped-token) not specified in this International Standard, the behavior is implementation-defined. **Any attribute-token that is not recognized by the implementation is ignored.** [ Note: Each implementation should choose a distinctive name for the attribute-namespace in an
> attribute-scoped-token. —end note ]

So, if you're using a standard, or implementation, prior to `[[nodiscard]]` being supported, it will just be ignored (so long as the standard is new enough to at least recognize an attribute (C++11))

`[dcl.attr.nodiscard]/2` states

> Appearance of a nodiscard call as a potentially-evaluated discarded-value expression is discouraged unless explicitly cast to void. Implementations are encouraged to issue a warning in such cases.

In your code, the result of `foo()` is not discarded; it is used in the output of `std::cout<<foo()<<std::endl;`.

Comment: when I try here https://godbolt.org/z/zE4WE4cEE. gcc trunk produces error for `[[nodiscard]]` when compiled with `-std=c++98`.

Comment: ...oh, thats because attributes were only introduced in c++11

Comment: Yes, I had edited to say that you need a standard to at least recognize attributes. Just edited to add that it was c++11

Comment: @ChrisMM, i have just tried to modify my code from "std::cout<<foo()<<std::endl;" to " foo();", when i compile with option -std=c++11, compiler outputs the warning message of " ignoring return value of ‘int foo()’". it seems that [[nodiscard]] works even with -std=c++11 option.

Comment: @jonas, most likely they implemented it for 17, then decided to allow it for 11 and 14 as well. Before `nodiscard` was standardized, it could be treated as implementarion defined, so they could still have it work, even prior to it being standardized, without breaking any rules.